# Why NRF24L01+ modules set RPD bit when detecting a signal above -64 dBm on the channel?

Tags: rf, wireless, radio, wifi, nrf24l01

Why the value -64dBm?

Is it because anything above this value and the receiver is unable to decode any valid packet on the channel?

Does this have anything to do with receiver sensitivity?

Can this be used to scan the spectrum for channels with low interference, free from WiFi transmissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction to -64dBm and also the 40us (I think?) delay is mainly so that people don't try and build an AM (de)modulator with the NRF. It's, in theory, able to decode packets at down to -95dBm. And yes, you can use it to find out which channels have ongoing traffic by tuning in on the channel, waiting long enough and reading the RPD bit.